# How to echo a specific data from an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I want to take a specific from an array I have created.

Here's the code:

```
        try
    {
    // Conecting to MySQL
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=horse', 'root', '');
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
    // ERROR MESSAGE
    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    // Fetching the data from the table
    $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM videos');

    $vidarray = array();

    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
    {
    $videolink = $donnees['link'];

    $vidarray = array($videolink);

    print_r($vidarray);
    }
    echo $vidarray[1]);

    $reponse->closeCursor(); // Closing the request
```

I want to echo one of these specific data like this

```
echo $array[1];
```

I want this to output "WubVcOaW-qs" with this.

I am relativly new to php and I am sure this is pretty basic but can't find it anywhere.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you getting this array ??? it looks like you are running `print_r` already on them individually

Comment: I use print_r just to show me the structure of the array actually within a loop. Thanks

Comment: Can you just add your loop to the question using edit

Comment: @Baba Just updated it. It seems that the code from Raidenace is working but I am now wondering how to fill that array with my loop.

Comment: Replace `print_r($vidarray);` with ` echo $vidarray[1]` and remove the echo from where you added it

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array(
'S01tE08GSNg',
'WubVcOaW-qs',
'2n0ag4qmG5g',
'ni1UR-lXiZo',
'ynvz8P_aFwk'
);

echo $array[1];
```

Comment: hum.... ok. I was knowing that was pretty stupid question. so simple like that. Thank you man!